# Issue with TimeSpan totalseconds in c#

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, timespan, datetimeoffset

I have a block of code that has to calculate code executing duration. The method where the block is called every second via DispatcherTimer.

As you can see from photo a span4.totalseconds is about 0, but the (DateTimeOffset.Now - now2) duration is about 1 second.

[image: What's going on?]

```
//some code here
span4 = DateTimeOffset.Now - now2; 
someInfo.Text = (DateTimeOffset.Now - now2).TotalSeconds.ToString();
now2 = DateTimeOffset.Now;
```

Comment: To measure code execution time I would use a StopWatch class, but perhaps I have misunderstood your problem

Comment: `DateTimeOffset.Now` actually means Now-now. You get the time at the moment of evaluation,ie when you add the watch. The second now could easily be called 1 second after the first Now during debugging

Comment: @Steve I need not exactly the execution time but rather time between different calls of method via Timer.Tick .

Comment: @Panagiotis  all watches were added several minutes ago. The breackpoint is on the last line, so i'm not debugging when it executes. now2 is set earlier when the method was previously called, and the goal is to know how much time passed between previous call and current.

Answer (score 3):

The way you measure execution time in .Net is using Stopwatch class:

```
Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
stopWatch.Start();
Thread.Sleep(10000);
stopWatch.Stop();

// Get the elapsed time as a TimeSpan value.
TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
```

Comment: True, but doesn't explain OP' issue. I'm quite sure that the same issue(one second difference) will also occur with the `Stopwatch`.

Answer (score 2):

because DateTimeOffset.Now will have a diferent value each time you call it... why you are doing the same substraction two times? try that:

```
span4 = DateTimeOffset.Now - now2; 
someInfo.Text = (span4).TotalSeconds.ToString();
now2 = DateTimeOffset.Now;
```

Comment: the problem is that span4.totalseconds equals 0, but if i watch (DateTimeOffset.Now - now2).TotalSeconds it's equals about 1 second. The correct value is 1 second? though.

Comment: the correct value will depend in the moment when you are calling it, that value will change every second

Comment: I call it every second via DispatcherTimer